# Woocommerce : Change order status to pending but do not increase stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Consider this example:

I have a product named "A" and there are 10 available in my store.

A user orders and pays for 3. The order status will change to "processing" and the stock reduces.

Now, I manually change The order status to "pending". The stock increases back to 10.

I want to prevent the increase from happening.

This is the code I am using, but does not appear to work:

```
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'pending' ) ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not work is WooCommerce actually has different functions for reducing stock and increasing stock - wc_reduce_stock_levels() and wc_increase_stock_levels(). The filter 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock' is in the function wc_reduce_stock_levels(). There is a corresponding filter 'woocommerce_can_restore_order_stock' in the function wc_increase_stock_levels(). Try using this filter instead.